# Return in a function while in loop

Tags: php, loops

I have a function, which checks a query, and then uses a while loop to extract data, I would like to return this data but I still want it to increment, but I read that return terminates a function, and thus would make it unable to increment. Is there a way around this?

```
$this->messages = array();
while($row = $data) {
                $this->messages[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
                $this->messages[$i]['title'] = $row['title'];
                $this->messages[$i]['message'] = $row['message'];
                $i++;
```

This loop is inside the function, I want to continue until the loop is done, but then I can't return any values.. is there a work around this?

Thank you

EDIT:

```
<?php

function Message($username){

            $query = "SELECT * FROM msg WHERE `to` = '".$this->userid."' && `to_viewed` = '0' && `to_deleted` = '0' ORDER BY `created` DESC";   
            $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute();

    $data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $num_rows = $stmt->fetchColumn();

        if($num_rows) {
            $i=0;
            $this->messages = array();
            while($row = $data) {
// want to return these 3 for each result
                $this->messages[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
                $this->messages[$i]['title'] = $row['title'];
                $this->messages[$i]['message'] = $row['message'];

                $i++;
            }
        } else {
            return 1; 
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: There are plenty of ways to return data after completing a loop but you're not being terribly clear about your goals here: can you clarify what you mean by 'I still want it to increment', or give some more of the code surrounding your function? And which values you want to return?

Comment: @davidf2281 Yes sorry

Comment: @user2693086 Could possibly a temp variable work? Save the data from the loop in a new variable and then increment that later.

Comment: @davidf2281 I added it into my original post. Basically, I want the loop to continue but I want to be able to return each result from the query.

Comment: @user2693086 Oh so you want to return each result of the loop?

Comment: A function can only return once. You need to return an array.

Comment: @JobanDhillon Yupp, sorry if it seems like a newbie question, has me stumped and annoyed :P

Comment: @Barmar returning an array won't do much if you have more than one result.. yo ucan return all 3 of those variables once return array (var1, var 2, etc).. but what if it increments more than once? How do I return those results?

Comment: You'll need to declare a new temporary results array before the loop; populate the array during the loop with each result; and then return the results array when the loop has finished.

Comment: You should be returning a two-dimensional array. The first dimension is the rows, the second dimension is each column in the rows. In fact, PDO has a method that does exactly this: use `fetchAll()` rather than `fetch`. And your code is acting as if you'd used `fetchAll`, because it's looping on `$data` as if it were an array of rows.

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more? with an example? I'm new to loops and arrays, thank you @davidf2281

Comment: It's 3am in England right now and I'm about to call it a day, but if nobody else has answered by tomorrow I'll get back to you :-)

Comment: @Barmar I have removed fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); and replaced it with fetchAll(), thank you for that.

Answer (score 4):

Use `PDO::fetchAll()`, it returns an array of all the results, rather than returning one row at a time:

```
function Message($username){

    $query = "SELECT * FROM msg WHERE `to` = '".$this->userid."' && `to_viewed` = '0' && `to_deleted` = '0' ORDER BY `created` DESC";   
    $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $this->messages = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $this->messages;
}
```

But to teach you about loops (a CS 101 concept -- what ever happened to people learning how to program?), here's how you would code it yourself:

```
    $stmt->execute();
    $this->messages = array();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
        $this->messages[] = $row;
    }
    return $this->messages;
```

Comment: suggested edit: `while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){` not `while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`